# store multiple output from loop as list

Tags: r

I want to store multiple output from for loop in one variable.

for example

```
dice <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

for (x in dice) {
    print(x)
 }
```

output I am getting :-

```
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
```

but I want output as list :-

```
[1] 1
[2] 2
[3] 3
[4] 4
[5] 5
[6] 6
```

and I want to access this list for different purpose . how I suppose to do it? thanks in advance?

Comment: It does print `1, 2, ...6`.  If you want as a list, use `as.list(dice)`

Comment: The values in the square brackets are just the nth elements of the vector coming out of the operation, which R provides in the console as a helper.

Comment: Printing doesn't have anything to do with accessing the list for different purpose. You already defined `dice` as an object--you can use that for whatever purpose you want.

Comment: umh! thanks all for quick reply @GregorThomas i want to access all loop iterations outside the loop and i want it as list!

Comment: I still don't understand. You can use `dice[3]` inside or outside of a loop. It's not at all clear why you're using a loop at all. You say "list" but the output you ask for looks like a vector. Maybe `data.frame(dice)` would be more to your liking? Or `matrix(dice, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(1:6, "dice"))`? I don't think there's a nice way to make a vector print one item per row--you can change the printed row width, e.g., `print(dice, width = 10)` which gets you down to 3 items per row, but `10` is the minimum allowed width for that print option.